# Any Echo value how to direct store in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a simple Business Management setup for office work. First I fetch all information from database. All is going well except the quantity input.

In this all payment doing calculate sum and do Echo. But I want that this echo value detect automatic store in database in another table.

so how to complete this?

This is the code of program.

```
<tbody>
<?php

    $respectivestud = mysql_query("select * from client where client_id");
    $i = 1;
    while($r_client = mysql_fetch_array($respectivestud))
    {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $r_client['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $r_client['project_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $r_client['cost']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $r_client['payment_1']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $r_client['payment_2']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $r_client['payment_3']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $r_client['payment_4']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $r_client['payment_5']; ?></td>
            <?php $total = $r_client['payment_1'] + $r_client['payment_2'] + $r_client['payment_3'] + $r_client['payment_4'] + $r_client['payment_5'];?>
            <td> <?php echo $total ; ?></td>
            <?php $remain = $r_client['cost'] - $total;?>
            <td><?php echo $remain; ?></td>             
        **<td>**
```

Comment: i can't understand "But i wanto tha this echo value ditect automatic store in database in another table."

Comment: Do not use the deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_` or `PDO` with prepared statement instead.

Comment: sry  
i was fatchinh the all value from the database and echo the all value in another page....and doing payment1+payment+pay3+pay4+pay5 and store the value in anoother variable and echo this variable value

bt i want the this echo value automatic store in the data base in another table not the manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you write valid PHP code. You are not closing your while and you are not closing tags correctly. This should be correct.

```
<tbody>
<?php

    $respectivestud = mysql_query("select * from client where client_id");
    $i = 1;
    while($r_client = mysql_fetch_array($respectivestud))
    {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $r_client['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $r_client['project_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $r_client['cost']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $r_client['payment_1']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $r_client['payment_2']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $r_client['payment_3']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $r_client['payment_4']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $r_client['payment_5']; ?></td>
            <?php $total = $r_client['payment_1'] + $r_client['payment_2'] + $r_client['payment_3'] + $r_client['payment_4'] + $r_client['payment_5'];?>
            <td> <?php echo $total ; ?></td>
            <?php $remain = $r_client['cost'] - $total;?>
            <td><?php echo $remain; ?></td>             
        </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
</tbody>
```

To save data you could use this:

```
$sql=mysqli_query($connection,"insert into `tablename`(`columnname`)values('".$total."')");
```

Answer (score 0):

foirst off all replace mysql_* with mysqli_* or Pdo statement. as mysql_* is depricated now . here is the reference [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) and [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) 
store the remaining ammount in a variable. then use this variable in update query . like

```
<td><?php echo $remaining_amount=$remain; ?></td>
```

then update in db

```
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
    $sql = "UPDATE MyGuests SET tablename='".$remaining_amount."' WHERE id=yprimarykey";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <td><?php echo $r_client['payment_5']; ?></td>
 <?php $total = $r_client['payment_1'] + $r_client['payment_2'] +$r_client['payment_3'] + $r_client['payment_4'] + $r_client['payment_5'];?>
 <td> $sql=mysqli_query($connection,"insert into `tablename`(`columnname`)values('".$total."')");</td>
```

you can do like this whatever the value you want to insert...

Comment: I have do this.....

<?php $total = $r_client['payment_1'] + $r_client['payment_2'] + $r_client['payment_3'] + $r_client['payment_4'] + $r_client['payment_5'];?>
         <td> <?php $sql=mysqli_query($connection,"insert into `pay_total`(`total_amount`)values('".$total."')");?></td>
        

but in this where  total values are echo is problem..."Notice: Undefined variable: connection in C:\xampp\htdocs\payment\all_client.php on line 55

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\payment\all_client.php on line 55"